# Cant add class when scroll

Tags: reactjs, scroll

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import './header.css'

const Header = () => {
const headerRef = useRef(null);

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
            headerRef.current.classList.add("header__shrink")
        }
        else {
            headerRef.current.classList.remove("header__shrink")
        }
    });
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll");
    };
}, [])
```

}

[image]
[image]In file Header.jsx

Comment: Can you show the place where you add ref attribute to an element?

Comment: I was updated new image, Is that the image you need?

Comment: no, headerRef must be added to element. Elements placed in return section